# swift BackgroundTasks BGTaskScheduler register never get inside block

Tags: swift, xcode, background-process

In a SwiftUI app i try to use BackgroundTasks. However, while .register() does indeed get called, it does not get inside its closure. Followed the docs, enabled background options, added permission background identifiers and then the code.

```swift
@main
struct taskbackApp: App {
  @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
    }
  }

  class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(
      _ application: UIApplication,
      didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil
    ) -> Bool {
      registerBackgroundTask()
      return true
    }

    func registerBackgroundTask() {
      BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: "fr.airbus.taskback", using: nil) {
        task in
        self.handleBackgroundTask(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask)
      }
    }

    func handleBackgroundTask(task: BGAppRefreshTask) {
      print("Performing background task...")
      task.setTaskCompleted(success: true)
    }
  }
}
```

I add Permitted background task scheduler identifiers = fr.airbus.taskback in info.plist
background fetch and background processing are enabled i launch the application on a real device with version 16.5.1